# Removing "_embedded" property in Spring RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2 (with oAuth2 2.3.3) and HATEOAS (I have a dependency file that says I'm using it even though my focus isn't that) to build a RestAPI. I have no problem making requests and getting the responses. However when I request a collection/page I get the response inside a "_embedded" object, like so:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "users" : [ {
      "firstName" : "Stuff",
      "lastName" : "ToDo",
      ...
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Things1",
      "lastName" : "Does",
      ...
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/user{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/user"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/user/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Is it possible to remove the "_embedded" property or replace it by something like "content"?

I tried adding this property on my application.yml:

spring:
 hateoas: 
    use-hal-as-default-json-media-type: false

I also tried without the "-":

useHalAsDefaultJsonMediaType: false

No luck. I also tried adding the following header values on the request but it doesn't work properly:

"Accept: application/hal+json" gives same response
or 
"Accept: application/x-spring-data-verbose+json" gives me a 406 Not Acceptable.

Here's my Resource:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'")
public interface UserRepositoryAndResource extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByLogin(@Param("login") String login);

    public Page<User> findByLoginContaining(@Param("login") String login, Pageable pageable);


}
```

I also have a controller that is used to expose the current user in a sessionless context. I'd rather not touch on this:

```
@Controller
public class UserForTokenController {

    private UserRepositoryAndResource repo;

    @Autowired
    public UserForTokenController(
            UserRepositoryAndResource repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @GetMapping("user/current")
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> getForToken(OAuth2Authentication auth) throws UserNotFoundException {
        String authUser = (String) auth.getPrincipal();
        String login = authUser;
        User user = Optional.of(repo.findByLogin(login)).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(UserModel.build(user));
    }

}
```

Really clueless about what to do at the moment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are not sure about the property in your yml file, add a `bootstrap.properties` or `application.properties` that contains your property (`spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false`)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with Spring HATEOAS yet.

---

I'm going to assume you are using Spring version 4.1 or later and you return an object with your `@RequestMapping` method in your rest controller.

To modify a response, you can implement the `ResponseBodyAdvice` interface which is called before the response is written back to the client. The `MyResponse` class holds the content I want to modify in this example. It has a single `String` property named content.

If my `@RequestMapping` method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/q50646303")
  public MyResponse q50646303() {
    MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
    myResponse.setContent("content");
    return myResponse;
  }
```

I can change the content of the response like this:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyResponseBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<MyResponse> {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass) {
    return MyResponse.class == methodParameter.getParameterType();
  }

  @Override
  public MyResponse beforeBodyWrite(MyResponse myResponse, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType,
      Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest,
      ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
    //Change your content here
    myResponse.setContent("edited content");
    return myResponse;
  }
}
```

If I call the URL `{"content":"edited content"}` is printed. Maybe you can use this to edit the response the way you want?

For future questions it would be helpful if you include a bit more information like the versions of the frameworks used or the relevant code (of your RestController, in this case).

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. I will edit my main post after this.

I'm actually using a @RepositoryRestResource.

I'm not sure if I can do what you're suggesting but I'm going to try it anyway.

Thanks again.

EDIT: Updated main post with more relevant info

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer :) Let me know if you could resolve your problem, if not I'll check it out again.